# Activity takes a decade to open because I get Firebase queries at on Create

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

```
private fun getAngryMovies() = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
    try {
        val querySnapshot = allMoviesCollectionReference
            .whereEqualTo("type", "Angry")
            .get().await()

        for (document in querySnapshot.documents) {
            val movieObj = document.toObject<AngryMovies2>()
            if (!innerAngryMovieList.contains(movieObj)) {
                innerAngryMovieList.add(movieObj!!)
            }
        }

        showContent = true
        withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
            main()
        }


    } catch (e: Exception) {
        withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
            e.printStackTrace()
            Log.e("a7a", e.message.toString())
        }
    }
}
```

The thing is I'm running this function as long as splash screen is shown in a Coroutine Spread as shown above .The thing is the activity takes a decade to open. I'm probably querying over 100 movies, how should I solve this issue

Comment: A loading spinner? :-) Or have another view on your data which is just the titles for example, to make it load those quicker, whilst loading the rest later. Your question also depends on your UX, this is why recycler views have adapters to only load what is bvisible.

Comment: I have a splash screen, that only goes away whne the function is finished, the things is that it takes a decade as I said

Comment: Why do you have to wait for it? Could you let them carry on using your app and the data will load when its ready? Your question is a philisophical one :-) You could try pagination: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/query-cursors

Comment: You could cache the items locally (e.g. in a database), show these cached items immediately upon app open and then when you get the new list from Firebase update the locally stored items and re-load the list

Comment: This wouldn't solve the issue, the issue is that the function takes a lot of power of something like that, but the function it self would run even if I had a local database shown, it would still run to get the changes